# How to get TAG value/text (like innerHTML)?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get TAG value (not innerHTML)? Lets supose i have a... link or image.

```
<link href="bla"> | <img src="ble" />
```

let suppose there is only 1 link in a document:

```
var links = document.link;
```

how to get TAG text as: '`<link href="bla">`' by JS (cause innerHTML is empty cause there is not text INSIDE tag, cause it does not have ending >)?

Comment: I'm sensing an XY problem. Why would you ever want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DOM element attribute outerHTML

```
$(selector)[0].outerHTML
```

which  gets the first DOM element of the selection and then acquires the html using the DOM attribute outerHTML

If you do not want the content but only the enclosing tag you could do this

```
$.fn.tag = function(){
    return this[0].outerHTML.replace(this.html(),"");
};
```

Comment: ohhh I didn't know about this command - outerHTML, THANKS! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear the question, but I expect you want the attribute value

```
var href = $(link).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this (pure JS):

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0];
```